# Show raw SQL in Django with DEBUG=True & for delete() and save()

Tags: python, django

There is any posibility to see raw sql when DEBUG=True and DEBUG=False? And for methods delete() and save()?
I want to log all requests for my app, and I don't understand how I can log raw sql.

Comment: https://github.com/django-debug-toolbar/django-debug-toolbar

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you read [docs on logging](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging).

You need the [`django.db.backends` logger](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging/#django-db-backends) and [`RequireDebugFalse` filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging/#django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse).

Example settings:

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'filters': {
        'require_debug_false': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse'
        }
    },
    'handlers': {
        'console':{
            'level':'DEBUG',
            'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
            'class':'logging.StreamHandler',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.db.backends': {
            'handlers':['console'],
            'propagate': True,
            'level':'DEBUG',
        },
    }
}
```

Note: you can also enable SQL query logging in the SQL server configuration, without touching django. Refer to your SQL server documentation for details.

Comment: It looks like I miss somethig( I added your code to settings.py, added 
`import logging;
l= logging.getLogger('django.db.backends');
l.setLevel(logging.DEBUG);
l.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler())`
to views.py, I can see log messages in console, but I don't understand how to see an sql...

Comment: With `Debug=False` it doesn't work, with `Debug=True` - works. It looks like with DEBUG=False it can't work: `For performance reasons, SQL logging is only enabled when settings.DEBUG is set to True, regardless of the logging level or handlers that are installed.`

Comment: Are you about logging? No.