# Saving sql query in runtime Django

Tags: django

I use Django ORM to create complex SQL queries dynamically, I want to save ---while running--- the SQL query that Django builds for future use, I have not found a proper way to do it.

As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1074224) there are two ways to access a query but only `connection.queries` contains a valid query, and needed to set `debug=True`.

Because I want to do it in the product environment, `debug=True` is not really a solution for me, and I don't want to change the Django source code.

Any solution/comment can help me.

I use Django 2.2.

Comment: If you want to log the queries, this is not the way to do it

Comment: @AhmedI.Elsayed I need the query to run it later from lambda in aws, so i want to save it in the DB.

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on how you want to save and re-use these queries.

If you want to store/use the queries **outside** the Django application, I would recommend changing the logging settings, for example, as done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17469314/5418359). See also the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/logging/). If necessary, the logging could also be done at the SQL database itself rather than in Django.

Saving and re-using queries **inside** the Django application seems to be tricky, and there are security reasons why the `connection.queries` only works in debug environments. One could try a similar approach as laid out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7181511/logging-django-sql-queries-with-debug-set-to-false).

Comment: Thanks for your response.
I want to save the query in db, it seems that the RequireDebugFalse setting is not useful because Django writes the query to the log only in case 'debug=true', please correct me if I am wrong.
Another point is that I need to save the query in the DB with parameters sent in the http request, so I'm not sure if a log can help.

Comment: Then I would suggest an approach as mentioned [here](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/17741#comment:4), to get the full query with parameters filled in.